How to merge two different Fields from different databases with INFLUX?
i will make it shorter possible...
I have renamed some entities in homeassistant and moved to a new database, and wish to merge the old with the new one.
I wish to merge the results of those two queries:
src db:
SELECT "value" FROM "homeassistant_global"."autogen"."W" WHERE "entity_id"='consumo_istantaneo'

dest db:
SELECT "value" FROM "provamigrate"."autogen"."W" WHERE "entity_id"='gar_consumo_istantaneo'

I have tried several ways...
This one works, but does not "rename" the Measurement:
SELECT "value" INTO "provamigrate"."autogen"."W" FROM "homeassistant_global"."autogen"."W" WHERE "entity_id"='consumo_istantaneo' GROUP BY *
how i can copy in a different entity_id ?
(INTO "provamigrate"."autogen"."W"."gar_consumo_istantaneo")
